# HTML input submit a list of items that are variable

Tags: html, input

I've got a Jquery UI sortable list with add item option. I want to gather these items up and submit them. what input type should I use?

Comment: Take a look at the serialize method of the sortable list.http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: thanks - what should the HTML input type be for this

Comment: The serialize method returns a string, so you can use a text input, or a hidden one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `serialize` method of the sortable object (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/). This method returns a string that you can send using a text input or a hidden one.